# Setting the value of input type date in MS Edge

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, date, datepicker, microsoft-edge

So I set the input value in Razor but the screen shows 'mm/dd/yyyy'. It isn't until i choose a date from the picker that it will show the date.

[image]

I inspected the element and found that even though it is displaying 'mm/dd/yyyy' it still had the correct value.

[image]

CanIUse says that edge does support 'date'. So is this just a bug or does Edge not support preset values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not just Edge-related. Any HTML5 compliant browser that supports the various input types related to date and time expects the input's value to be in [ISO 8601 format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). For a date type, that would be `YYYY-MM-DD`. If the value of the field is not in this format, it is treated as non-existent, so you get the default placeholder.

The reason for this is that there's way too many different ways of displaying date/time in various cultures across the planet. Instead of attempting to try to parse an arbitrary string value into a date, the parser only works on ISO 8601 dates. However, the browser will then localize the *display* for the individual user (`mm/dd/yyyy`, in your case).